# Timing with Swing animation

Tags: java, swing, animation, timer

i have some problems with Swing and animate a character,
I Have a JFrame with key listener and when the user hit down,it calls my JPanel method here

```
for(int i=1;i<4;i++)
{           
    pY+=16;
    g.drawImage(perso,pX,pY,pX+50,pY+50,0+50*i,0,50+50*i,50,this 
    this.repaint();                 
}
```

This animate my character but so fast that we can see a thing,how do i can do to view the animation?

Answer (score 7):

The answer is already given by Jonas (use a Swing timer), but it might be useful to explain why you are not seeing the animation, and why the timer is the best solution for this problem.

**Why do I not see the different repaints**

When you call `JComponent#repaint` the `JComponent` is not repainted. Instead, an asynchronous request to repaint a certain component is scheduled on the EDT. If you invoke many `repaint` calls, Swing might decide to group those requests and repaint the component just once.

I did not immediately found an official reference for this in the Oracle documentation (the [Swing painting article](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/painting/index.html#mgr) does not seem to mention it). The only place where I found this was in a note in [this article](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/threads/threads1.html), but I am pretty certain this is documented somewhere.

**Why is using a `Timer` the best solution**

For an animation, you basically want to say:

> my character should move `x` pixels in `y` milliseconds

And preferably, you want to have a smooth animation on screen so you need to repaint rather frequently. If you keep in mind that

- All interaction with the Swing components should happen on the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread,  see the [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) article for more info)
- You should never block the EDT as this will freeze your UI, meaning you cannot 'wait' in the EDT until a repaint is done or the repaint will never happen
- Repaint requests can be grouped, so calling repaint `x` times does not guarantee you that your `paint` method is called `x` times as well

The solution to overcome this limitations is to use a `Timer`. With the same example (moving a character on screen), you can use a `Timer` to update the position of the character and schedule a repaint. Since the `Timer` code is triggered on the EDT, you do not violate the Swing threading rules.

In the `paintComponent` method of your component, you then paint the character at the current location. This might be the 'previous location + 1', or the 'previous location +2' (or ...) depending on how many times the `Timer` has been triggered between the previous `paint` call and the current `paint` call. This ensures the speed at which your character moves is system-independent. Only the smoothness of the animation will depend on your system (as in: how many repaint requests get grouped).

The [Swing `Timer` tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) to which Jonas already linked contains more information.

Comment: Thank your for this detailed informations,it will be very useful to me,i will try with a timer then

Comment: @mKorbel Thanks. Unfortunately it does not seem to get many upvotes :-(

Answer (score 3):

1. don't extend `JFrame`, create `JFrame` as local variable
2. don't use `KeyListener`, use `KeyBindings` instead
3. don't paint directly to the `JFrame`, use `drawImage()` to the `JLabel` or `JComponent/JPanel`
4. > This animate my character but so fast that we can see a thing,how do i can do to view the animation?

another issue with `KeyListener`, you have to set for delay betweens two `KeyEvents`

Answer (score 2):

You can use a Swing Timer and update the animation in regular intervals. See [How to Use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)