# Using threads in Swing GUI in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I am using the following codes, to replace a `JLabel` each 0.5 seconds, with the same sentence but with another dot.

```
    Runnable r1=new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(true){
                try {
                    connectionStatus.setText("Connection Established...");
                    Thread.sleep(500L);
                    connectionStatus.setText("Connection Established.");
                    Thread.sleep(500L);
                    connectionStatus.setText("Connection Established..");
                    Thread.sleep(500L);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {

                }
            }
        }
    };
Thread th1=new Thread(r1);
th1.start();
```

Is this the real purpose from using threads? Does this affect the speed of the program? If the thing that I'm doing is so stupid, is there any other way to do such stupid things?

Comment: Dots to indicate progress?  Wow, I'm back in the 80s.  The mirror-balls are spinning & I'm ready to boogie!  After your nostalgia trip, join us in the 10s & use a **`JProgressBar`.**

Comment: @AndrewThompson +1 for the laugh. I'd give another one for not using "the 80s called and (...)" but I can't. It's very good advice as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is this the real purpose from using threads?

If you want these operations to run in **parallel** then the answer is yes

> is there any other way to do such stupid things?

If you update your label at a fixed intervals then you should probably go for using [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)s instead

On a side note:

- You should avoid using `while(true)` when doing multithreading, you should either define a stop boolean that you test in the loop or use `Thread.interrupted()` if you extend the `Thread` class
- When updating UI elements from non EDT thread, you should use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater`

Answer (score 4):

Try using a `Timer` from Swing library instead. It's generally a better idea to use these for GUI-related tasks. This will especially come in handy when you try to use timed events on multiple components as all Timers share the same timer thread.

It also provides a flexible and intuitive programming model based on listeners.

No need to reinvent the wheel.

[Timer tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

***EDIT:***

A little followup on the wheel reinvention part. You should also take Andrew Thompson's suggestion into consideration. There are components in Swing that have been designed specifically to indicate progress. It's unnecessary to do it using a label, as you're trying to do. Take a look at [`JProgressBar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JProgressBar.html). It's going to be simple and it will look more professional.

Answer (score 4):

First one suggestion, rather use something like this:

```
while(!isStopped) {
  // do some work
}
```

With your approach you just created infinity loop.

**Note:** Have look at [Java Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html). It's very usefull and efficient.

Comment: In a Swing context, you should look at `javax.swing.Timer` instead of the `java.util.Timer`

Answer (score 4):

There are several issues with this code.

1. Swing components should be accessed/updated on the Event Dispatch Thread and are not thread-safe. So starting another Thread to update your `JLabel` is simply not done. See the ['Concurrency in Swing'](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) tutorial for more information
2. Even if you would call the code above on the EDT, you would not see any updates of the `JLabel` as the `Thread.sleep` would block the EDT, and avoiding a repaint.

So the solution is to use the [`javax.swing.Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) class, which allows to perform operations on the EDT at regular intervals, and does not block the EDT in between. See also the [`Timer` tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html). As a side effect, using timers avoids the `while(true)` loop which would never end.

You can find a more complete answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11088910/timing-with-swing-animation/11090056#11090056).

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

1. You will need the above approach if your purpose is **parallel processing**.
2. You have given **while (true)** , which will lead to a **Infinite loop, you must control it,
   its better to have a boolean variable** to control the nos. of iteration of the while loop.
3. **Keep you non-ui thread processing OUT of the Event Dispatcher Thread**, else you will make the GUI hang till 
   your thread has finished its run() method. In your case its Infinite, as while (true).
4. If you want to **sync** the **non-ui work and ui work**, then you can use **Handler or Swing-Worker.**
5. Last but not the least, Take a look at **TimeTask**, see this link

   http://enos.itcollege.ee/~jpoial/docs/tutorial/essential/threads/timer.html